# Return object from Javascript to blade and then to controller

Tags: laravel

I have a question about how to pass data from Javascript to my blade and then in return to my controller in Laravel.
My goal is to verify if a specific user id exists but later in the controller also use next to their verified ID also their mail address. With a jquery I am checking if a specific user count exists in the LDAP like this:

```
url: "getADobject/" + $('#supervisor').val(),
data: '',
dataFilter: function(data) {
                  var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

                  $(".loading").css('visibility', 'hidden');
                  for ( var i = 0; i < parsedData.user_details.length; i++) {
                    console.info(parsedData.user_details[i]);
                    if(parsedData.user_details[i].uid === $('#supervisor').val()){
                      console.info("Found user in JSON: " + JSON.stringify(parsedData.user_details[i]));
                      return true;
                    }
                  }

                  return false;
                },
```

This actually works and in the blade the input text field double-checks if the user exists in the LDAP. As you can also see, I just check for a specific value (user_details[i].uid) from the returned data and then return true or false. However, in my next step, after hitting the Send button in my blade, I want to have in the request parsedData variable in the controller the supervisors mail address, which I already had once requested.

My problem is, right now, I am checking just if the user exists, but not doing anything more with the result data. I could of course request the data again in the controller but this would be the same request again. Therefore, my question would, how can I save the parsedData in a kind of global variable so that later in my controller, in the Request $request, the data is also available, without displaying it in the blade in a new, or hidden, field.

Thanks in advance

Stephan

---

Update because of space issues in the comment section:

Hi there,

At first, thanks for your detailed comment. I have to admit, I am very new too web development and just try something out, so I don’t understand 100% what you are assaying me ;)

When I do the validation through JQuery I ask my LDAP controller to check the entered username. I don’t want that the user can add a supervisor who does not exist. This controller already returns all required information that I would love to give already back to the blade’s controller that I will later use when I click the Submit Button and gets redirected to the function: public function store(Request $request), with all other filled out information from this blade, which I can access by: $request->input('firstname');.

So, you are suggesting I call the function axios.post and use this to submit all data or can I use it various times, to pass the data from the LDAP controller as well as the data from the blade form?

---

Currently my $request variable in the controller looks like this:

```
array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "VN7dFO2X1T1jfwfVduhRmxQFZDrli058Z8iJ6voi"
  "username" => "king"
  "firstname" => "Plow"
  "secondname" => "King2"
```

But I would like to add another variable like:

```
  "mailaddress" => "King@hotmail.com"
```

which I like to define though the jquery in javascript where the data from the controller contains this information but I don’t want to define an extra field in my blade like for firstname:

```
<div><input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Update User" class="btn btn-primary">
```

---

Ok,
What I could do is just add this so my javascript:

```
document.getElementById("supervisormail").value = parsedData.user_details[i][0].mail[0];
```

and this to my blade:

```
<input type="hidden" id="supervisormail" name="supervisormail" >
```

But I am not that happy with the solution. Would be nicer, I guess, if I could just add it due javascript without any modifications in the blade

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass data from javascript to php that way. What I would recommed you is to create a new controller or add a new method to an existing controller which expect the data you want to pass to your blade.

So you could simply use axios for this case like this:

```
axios.post('/your/route', yourdata)
     .then(response => {
        // scucess
        console.log(response.data);
     })
     .catch(error => {
       // error
       console.log(error.data);
     });
```

And in your controller's method to get the request and work from there further you can simply do this:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    dd($request->all()
}
```

Comment: Hi, I added my first post because of space issues here

Comment: @Stephan so what is the current issue?

Comment: I added another update. Or is your suggestion I do the submit action by a javascript function?